# I'm trying to make an app in Android which can edit PDF, and I don't want to use any paid library

Tags: android, pdf

I'm trying to make an app in Android which can edit PDF, and I don't want to use any paid library. Please help me out on this, and if you know any library which is free then let me know.
What ever I have search i have got paid libraries like eg. IText etc.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I'm trying to open the PDF file in convas soo that it can be edited.But am not getting the path that how to load pdf in a canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know **ebookdroid libaray** which is great for pdf handling on android but i used only for viewing pdf file.Im not sure whether it allows you to edit pdf or not.Just check it out this library.

> Here is the link:http://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/